# Trying to copy a specific cell from one sheet and append to last available row on another

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create simple code for a google spreadsheet I have that tracks my investment accounts.

I would like to create a script that I can set on a time trigger to run after the market closes to record my account balance on a daily basis.

So far I have come up with:

```
function recordHistory() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Account");
 var source = sheet.getRange("B7");
 var values = source.getValues();
 values[0][0] = new Date();
 var historicalData = ss.getSheetByName("EOD Data");
 var newData = [];
 for (var key in values) {
 if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  newData.push(values[key][0]);
 }
}
historicalData.appendRow(newData);
};
```

My experience with scripts is very limited as I am very new to this.  This is what I have managed to cobble together from examples found here and on the web.

This only returns the date and time the script was ran to Column A on the EOD Data sheet.  Cell B7 on the "Accounts" sheet is the data I want to record, the first available row on "EOD Data" is where I would like it to be placed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the same thing with my investments. I set a trigger to run daily at 10 pm. The first part of the code checks the day of the week. If it is Sat or Sun it does not run.

```
function recordHistory() {
dow=new Date();
var dow=dow.getDay();
if(dow==0 || dow==6){
return;
}
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Account");
 var source = sheet.getRange("B7");
 var values = source.getValue();
 var historicalData = ss.getSheetByName("EOD Data");
 var lr=historicalData.getLastRow()+1
 var range = historicalData.getRange(lr , 1, 1, 1);//last row of col A
 range.setValue(new Date().toString());
 var range = historicalData.getRange(lr, 2, 1, 1);//last row of col B
 range.setValue(values);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.  The day of the week code is a nice bonus.